# Trying to delete files via a scheduled task and VBScript

Tags: vbscript, ftp, windows-server-2008

I asked a previous question about downloading file unattended on a server, using VBScript and Windows Task Scheduler. (See
[Scripting SFTP unattended download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345678/scripting-sftp-unattended-download) )

That works great but now I also need to delete the files from the server I am calling:

```
Set sessionses = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    sessionses.Run "C:\TCS\SFTP\delThem.bat", , True
```

PSFTP calling a batch file that runs this command:

```
psftp user@host:22 -batch -b script.txt -pw pa$$word
```

script.txt is as follows:

```
cd FromCeridian
del *.GEN
```

If I run this command from the command line, or double click the batch file containing the command, it works "interactively", but when running unattended and scheduled, it doesn't do this part. The server is SFTP, so I can't just use win ftp commands to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check the security options of your task to verify the user identity has correct access privileges.

Comment: the task (and the script) downloads, moves, and deletes local files, but just doesn't seem to run the PSFTP batch command

Comment: also its the Administrator Account running with highest privileges